# Is it possible to animate curves profiles

Tags: animation

Is it possible to animate the properties of curved profiles?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not directly, unless I'm mistaken.. it's still just primitive creation? Could you give us an idea of the final effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I use the screw modifier for some masking methods, put it takes a few more clicks to achieve the results, but these primitive shapes, have much more creative options, so I was wondering if it was possible to animate some of their properties. But since it's not plausible, I'll stick to my usual method. Regards. :)

Comment: I'm sure there will be a GN solution, if otherwise it's a bit fiddly..